# Too many DNS zones. Need advice on what to do about them

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internal-dns

So we have someone here who loves creating DNS zones.  So much so that we now have 145 different zones.  80 of these have one A record each.  It has gotten to the point where we can't find anything easily any more.  Here is an example of some of the zones.

```
company.lan - main zone
company.com - another main zone
company.de - one A record.  This is for our German site.
company.fr - same as above but for France
```

There are about 80 different zones for all different countries.  Has anyone run into something like this and if so, how did you clean it up?  I just want a logical and readable DNS again.

Question is simply, is there a better way to manage TLDs in DNS other than having a separate zone for each TLD?

Comment: What's the technical problem here?

Comment: You don't. You have to have a zone for each TLD ...not really any way around it.

Comment: Sounds like you have two options.  1) Delete all the zones with one record and live with not being able to resolve company.[countrycode]. 2) Live with having a bunch of zones with only one entry in them.

Comment: Thank you Nathan.  I was afraid of that.  Oh well.  Thanks all.

Comment: Depending on what nameserver software you're using it may be possible to share data between zones (or alternatively automate changes to them) but, as has been pointed out, you will need all the zones if you care about them all working.

Comment: Just funny how there isn't a better way to do this.  It becomes quite difficult to find our main zones when scrolling through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no choice but to have a zone for each TLD due to how DNS works.